# How do I delete or change the date on a project data measurement?

Tags: derby, sonarqube

I ran an old copy of the code to have a baseline to compare to. Then accidentally ran the new code also set to back-dated. Can I change the date on the 2nd sample? can I delete the 2nd sample to do it over? I've gotten as far as using `ij` to connect to the derby db, but the output formatting looks bad, and I have no idea how to `select top 10 * from table` in derby to search for what table I should look at.

Comment: Sounds like you're just getting started. You'll probably want to pick up a book on databases to learn the basics of standard SQL. Also, rather than using IJ, trying using a friendlier tool, for example SQL Squirrel. It's much easier to browse around a database using Squirrel. But if you have to use "ij", read the manual carefully, and try starting with the commands "show tables" and "describe".

Comment: @ anonymous - any feedback on the -1 from whomever? @Bryan - Also i'm quite familiar with `SQL`, but that's years of `MS SQL`. so my statement was in the it's not my familiar sql, if it's something simple like `limit 500` like `MySqL` then I could figure that out, but the formatting ugliness of a command prompt remains. I'd really prefer to connect to any SQL db from `LinqPad`. If I thought `Toad` would work here, that'd be my 2nd choice.

Comment: Derby does have FETCH/OFFSET: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html#rrefsqljoffsetfetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in
2. Click project that contains the snapshot you want to delete.
3. `History Deletion` link on the left
4. Click the button that corresponds with the correct snapshot row.